# Can you specify return type mutability in Rust?

Tags: rust, immutability

Is it possible to specify the mutability of the assigned variable in rust? Something like

```
fn new(len: usize) -> Thing { ... }
fn new_mut(len: usize) -> mut Thing { ... }
```

I have a specific case where knowing the mutability of a type can be used to make several optimizations under the hood for my data structure.

Trying to enforce mutability manually is possible, but seems quite inelegant, especially when the concept of mutability is an intrinsic part of the rust language already. And you end up in weird situations like this:

```
// Thing::new() returns a data structure with an immutable backing type, 
// but the code below looks like it should be mutable.
let mut foo = Thing::new(5);
```

In this case, I either have to choice of trying to figure out if someone tried to make a mutable reference to my immutable `Thing` manually (and panicking I suppose), or by making `new` return a wrapper over `Thing` that hides all mutable functions (which means the `mut` keyword is rendered pointless and misleading).

Comment: per my knowledge, no. Because after the method returns, the ownership of the value is changed to the upper scope where the method is called from, so the method itself cannot control mutability at that point.

Comment: if mutable and immutable `Thing`s work that much differently, how about making them different types? `Thing` vs `ThingMut`.

Comment: I've hacked up [this code](https://play.rust-lang.org/?version=stable&mode=debug&edition=2018&gist=2558b030abfadd2f3d6fb9b1186172d7) where `Thing::new` returns an immutable _reference_. I'm not particularly sure if it's possible to encode mutability or immutability in a type that isn't a reference. It seems to me that mutability as seen in `let mut foo = Thing::new(5);` is a property of the _variable_, not its type. For that reason, AFAIK, it's not possible to write `let a: mut u32 = 42;`, because "expected type, found keyword `mut`", yet mutable _references_ are fine.

Comment: "It seems to me that mutability as seen in `let mut foo = Thing::new(5);` is a property of the variable, not its type." - that's correct. Moreover, due to the shadowing, it's possible to essentially change existing variable mutability: `let mut foo = Thing::new(5); do_something(&mut foo); let foo = foo;` is valid.

Comment: @Cerberus Also, the inverse is valid, which really throws some people off: `let foo = Thing::new(5); /* here foo is immutable */ ... let mut foo = foo; /* foo no longer immutable! */ ...`.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I think you have some misconception: mutability of a return type is not and should NOT be part of the function signature, mutability is always decided on the caller side.

The return type is a description of the memory slot returned to the caller when the call stack returns after executing the function. Ownership of the returned type is fully transferred, e.g. a `Thing` is fully moved to the caller. How the caller handles the returned memory cell is not the concern of the called function because it's already finished and returned. There's no such thing as mutable or immutable return type, mutability is always related to memory slots. In your example this is only decided at declaring variable `foo` that defines the memory slot of the result type on the caller side. As long as you have full ownership of a data structure, you're free to decide or even change mutability of the data.

What you're looking for is maybe a separate type specialized for optimization.

Comment: Not sure about the first phrase. `Vec::get_mut` and `HashMap::entry` return mutable references to the backing variable, while `Vec::get` returns a non mutable reference. So maybe using a wrapper like Option OP can achieve the same behaviour.

Comment: I understand your point, maybe my wording wasn't completely clear. What I meant is that mutability of the return value, i.e. in your case a reference itself is controlled by the caller. Whether the reference is readonly or can be reassigned to point somewhere else has nothing to do with the function signature and to be decided on the caller side. Mutability of the referenced data is a completely orthogonal topic and you're right that it is really a part of the signature.